# SOAP webservice: Python server and perl client

Tags: python, perl, web-services, soap

I have created a SOAP service (using spyne). I have used python on the server side. I have a python client that works perfectly fine. But, I want to reuse the output obtained from the server in a perl script (cannot use python).
One possible way would be to call the python client from within perl and capture STDOUT.
But, it would be nice if I could write a simple perl client to get the results. I wrote a simple perl client for SOAP following [this](http://www.iban-bic.com/soap_perl.html?&L=0), but my code did not print anything.

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new();
my $service = $soap -> service($URL);
print Dumper($service -> serverFunction($arg1,$arg2));
```

[Here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=182618) I found a discussion about perl server and python client.

So, is it possible to have a python server and perl client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but it's SOAP. See the notice from [SOAP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP::Simple):

*Let's face it. SOAP is painfull. It's a dumb idea, the only reason you should ever consider using SOAP is if someone holds a gun to your head or pay you a lot of money for it.*

If you want to build an API and have both server and client under your control: Try to avoid SOAP whenever possible. Consider switching to a JSON or basic HTTP API.

If you want to keep SOAP, I suggest to try [SOAP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP::Simple), it might work better than SOAP::Lite. There's also the [SOAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP) module, but it's probably too heavy for your usage case.

PS: You might want to include more details (e.g. code you tried) in your question to get a more specific answer.

Comment: I will have a look at SOAP::Simple and come back later. Btw, I tried the exact code mentioned in the link in my question. Is it absolutely necessary to write the hard code here?